# I'm having a problem with the visiblility of an object just in cycles

Tags: visibility

Im having a problem, an object is invisible in cycles, in eeve and in 3d view the visiblity is normal.

For detail, the object is invisible but selectable like its there but not visible and I'm using blender 2.90.1.

Thanks in advance.

[image: object not visible but selectable]

this second image shows that it doesent have a texture.

[image: object material]

I leave the file on a google drive
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQJs0wWLSZ90G9ixGXtRJOaOYFyJWGks/view?usp=sharing) < (this is the link)

Comment: Hello :). Does the material have any kind of transparency? That could explain why it's only visible in Eevee.

Comment: it has no texture, just the object

Comment: could it be a bug? should i report it?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say. You could also share the file, and I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: OK! I'll leave it in the post, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the problem, the visibility was turned off for the camera.

[image: visibility off for the camera]
[image: visibility on the camera enabled]

Comment: To make your scene easier to debug, I would have a tidy-up. Have a look through all those Boolean modifiers and knock out the ones that aren't actually making a difference to your components.